# Seaborn factor plot: Change bottom to a negative value

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am creating a factor plot within Seaborn. I have two different groups, where the mean for one group is a positive value and the mean of the other is a negative value. Therefore, one of the bars is facing upwards and the other is facing downwards.

```
g = sns.factorplot(x = "group",y="r_zscore", hue = "age_grp", data = z_score_all_temp, ci = 68, kind = "bar",legend = True,
              aspect = 2, alpha = .7)
```

[image: Current Plot]

Is there a way I can change the "bottom" to be a negative value so that both bars are facing upwards? Like this picture (I just added 0.6 to my values):

[image: Desired Plot]

In this example I am looking between two age groups (1 = younger adults, 2 = older adults) differences in z scored correlation coefficients (r_zscore). Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Can you please provide a [mcve] which one can change to provide a solution here? If I still need to guess what `z_score_all_temp` is, I will rather answer some another questions, which do provide some code to work with.

Comment: Why not `abs()` each group's mean?

Comment: I would still like to keep the same scale of the values on the y-axis (ie, have group 1's mean still be positive and group 2's mean still be negative).